# java file system WatchService not picking up file when file is created by another java programm

Tags: java

I have implemented WatchService on file system directory. There is another java process which writes to this directory. When i manually create a file in directory, WatchService is able to pick that up but when another java process creates a file in that directory, WatchService is not able to pick that up.
I'm using below sample code to write to a file.

```
 com.google.common.io.Files.write("test content".getBytes(), new File("/var/tmp/dir/1.txt"));
```

Comment: Maybe there's a problem in your code.

Comment: Could we see the code that creates a file in the directory?

Comment: @FunnyGeeks updated the question with code I'm using to write to a file.

Comment: Does the new file get picked up after the JVM finishes the process which programmatically creates the file?

Comment: no. The code which is creating a file is in shutdown hook. After writing a file JVM terminates but file is not getting picked up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the mounted NFS file system. Had to use Apache File Watcher API to resolve the issue.